# Why does our Views Block not get updates with node updates until we force Clear all Cache?

Tags: views

We have a View of nodes with two displays. The first is Slick Carousel **block** that shows some slides (images from nodes) and another display that is a Page used for drag and drop sorting (using Draggable Views).

When an admin changes the sort order of the nodes (slides) this change is not reflected for anonymous users until an admin can clear the site caches.

The View's cache setting is currently set to "Tag-Based" but setting it to "None" has the same result.

Is the issue that the Block is being cached even though its View's setting is Tag or Off?

In short, how can we have the Views Block update when an admin changes the sort order of the Nodes in the View?

[image]

Comment: Is this an issue with the module Draggable Views (check the issue queue) or is caching broken also if you update other things like for example the content of a node? Then you would need to check how the View is rendered. It might be rendered too early, when the page render context has not been initialized yet, or only parts of the View result, missing cacheable metadata.

Comment: Tag-based will depend on one of the nodes in the view to change.

Comment: Yes, and also when nodes are created or deleted (via the list tag). If this tag-based caching is not working then there is something very wrong.